# websocket sampler throwing Null response while opening socket connection

Tags: websocket, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image: Here is my sampler Error looks like]

The version of jmeter i'm using is 5.3
and the setting I'm using here is https://prnt.sc/zothxr for the web socket

I need to give load in the websocket using this jmeter & websocket

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [plugin source code](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/blob/master/src/main/java/JMeter/plugins/functional/samplers/websocket/ServiceSocket.java#L189) it appears that the session is not established so you might need to check your hostname/path/implementation and look at server and [JMeter log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) files, it might be the case you didn't install the necessary dependencies or something like this.

Also the plugin you're using is kind of outdated so I would recommend switching to [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/), it can be installed via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) and it has more features comparing to the version you're using.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)